# How can I store value before session got expired in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have different login pages for different roles, after logout, it should go to the corresponding user role's login page.

But after the session is expired it will redirect to an error page due to the session being expired. How do I store a value before the session becomes expired? I am using below code for:

```
if(authentication==null)
{
    response.sendRedirect("/home");
}
else
{   
    String id=authentication.getName();
    logger.info("Logout Sucessfull with Principal: " + 
    authentication.getName());
    UserEmailMapping user = userService.getByUserId(id);
    Role role=user.getRole();

    if(role==Role.ADMIN || role==Role.SYSTEMADMIN || role==Role.USER)
    {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        //redirect to login
        response.sendRedirect("/login");
    }
    else if(role==Role.PATIENT || role==Role.DOCTOR ){response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
    {
        //redirect to home
        response.sendRedirect("/home");
    }   
}
```

Comment: You want to save the role before the session expires so you can know to which login you should redirect your user after the session expire page ? Is this an embedded application, how in a first place you know to which login to redirect a user that has tried to reach your application for first time ?

Comment: This seems backwards.  As part of a **common** login look up the user's roles and direct the user to the appropriate page.